# To log all changes to a table using a trigger would the event need to be before or after

Tags: mysql, triggers, delimiter

Here is a table called user_log:

```
CREATE TABLE user_log (
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  user_id INT (10),
  name VARCHAR (50),
  username VARCHAR (32),
  password VARCHAR (32),
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  user_type_id INT (11),
  created DATETIME NOT NULL
  );
```

To create a trigger that will log all changes to the users table into the user_log table above. It should insert the OLD values into the log table.

Here is what I have:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER changes_log AFTER UPDATE ON user_log 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (OLD.user_id != NEW.user_id) THEN
        INSERT INTO user_log (id, name, username, password, email,
        user_type_id, created)
    VALUES(OLD.id, OLD.name, OLD.username, OLD.password, OLD.email,
    OLD.user_type_id, OLD.created, NOW(), 'Entry Updated');
    END IF;
END$$
```

Does this accomplish a successful trigger that will log all the changes to the users table into the user_log table I created above ?

Comment: Have you tried it? It looks like it should work, although a trigger could be written for either before or after.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an AFTER trigger. The AFTER trigger runs after the update has been made successfully in the users table. If there's an error that prevents the update from succeeding (like violation of a constraint or something like that), there will be no change and therefore no need to log it.

I note that you trigger logic logs the change only if the userid changes, because of this line:

```
IF (OLD.user_id != NEW.user_id) THEN
```

But what if any other column changes? Wouldn't you want to log changes if, for example, the user's email changes?